# Gnome-Extensions didn't install

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell

I am using arch linux and on that i installed gnome and chrome-gnome-shell (I use chrome as defualt browser) and then head up to https://extensions.gnome.org/. Firstly the site loads very slowly and then I install Gnome-shell-integration. I tried to install weather extension and then enable it. It didn't enable. I refresh the page and it still Off. I also use firefox but same result (and website timeout occurs very often in firefox).. I restart my computer and same.. How can i install extension?